# How to create an executable file for an AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I want to create an executable file that when run will send a popup. I have the code for the popup

`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "message"'`

but don't know how to create an executable file.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Comment: FWIW, you may not want to tell Finder to display the dialog, because that requires having the permissions to control that app via accessibility settings in recent macOS versions. You should be able to just do `display dialog "message"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Write your AppleScript in Script Editor.

   [image]
2. Choose **File** → **Save** and select **Application** as File Format.

   [image]

This gives you an .app which will run your AppleScript when opened.

[image]

Comment: But then you get all default values for bundle name, etc. Is there a way to set this up so the source file can be edited and recompiled without replacing all the other parts of the .app folder?

Answer (score 6):

1. Write your shell script in a text file, including the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

   [image]

   If you're just using AppleScript, you can use osascript as the shebang:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/osascript
   tell app "Finder" to display dialog "message"
   ```
2. Set the executable bit on the file.

   ```
   chmod +x /path/to/file
   ```

This gives you a file which will run your shell script when opened.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can save it as a script by putting this in a plaintext file and save it as something like *dialog.sh*:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "message"'
```

Then making the file executable in the terminal by running `chmod +x /path/to/dialog.sh`.
Execute in terminal by running `/path/to/dialog.sh`

Comment: This is creating a bash shell script which executes `osascript`... seems to me you should just make the shebang `#!/usr/bin/osascript` and then the content of the file can be a multi-line applescript (`tell app "Finder" to display dialog "message"`) ... but still seems like a workaround for the "proper" way of making an AppleScript executable from the finder: saving as an application

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript

tell app "Finder" to display dialog "message"
```

This seems to work for me.  It seems to be the canonical way to shebang for python3, so I figured I'd try the same thing for AppleScript.